# Create a histogram in OxyPlot using c# wpf

Tags: c#, histogram, oxyplot

I'm trying to create a histogram in oxyplot. I followed the documentation on oxyplot.org (using ColumnSeries) and ended up with a histogram looking like this:

[image]

And my code looks like this:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

             this.Items = new Collection<Item>
            { 
                new Item {Label="200", Value=37},
                new Item {Label = "400", Value=7},
                new Item {Label="600",Value=23},
                new Item {Label="800",Value=23},
                new Item {Label="1000",Value=23}
            };

            var model = new PlotModel {Title = "Column Series", LegendPlacement = LegendPlacement.Outside, LegendPosition = LegendPosition.RightTop, LegendOrientation = LegendOrientation.Vertical };

            model.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, ItemsSource = this.Items, LabelField = "Label" });
            model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, MinimumPadding = 0, AbsoluteMinimum = 0 });

            model.Series.Add(new ColumnSeries { Title = "2009", ItemsSource = this.Items, ValueField = "Value" });

            this.Model1 = model;
            this.DataContext = this; 
        }

        public Collection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public PlotModel Model1 { get; set; }

        public class Item
        {
            public string Label { get; set; }
            public double Value { get; set; }
        }


    }
}
```

I will add some other data eventually. My problem right now is that I want my "x-axis" to be linear and I also want my columns to fill upp the whole space between 0 to 200, and 200 to 400 etc. I've tried to change the axis to a LinearAxis but since I use OxyPlot's ColumnSeries I must have a CategoryAxis on the x-axis, otherwise it won't work. Can I change my CategoryAxis in some way so it looks like a LinearAxis or is it better to use another kind of series (already tried BarSeries and RectangleBarSeries, that didn't work either)? I also want to move the labels 200, 400, 600 etc. and place them under each "intervall line"

Comment: For anyone who has the same question: I managed to solve my problem by creating another LinearAxis which I added to my PlotModel and then I hid my CategoryAxis through IsAxisVisible which I put to "false". Not the best soulution, but at least it works :-)

Comment: You could answer your own question and provide the code for the workaround that you've found.